# Namespace alias for Doctrine

Tags: symfony, namespaces, doctrine

I became responsible for a large legacy web application and I am trying to slowly refactor it into the Symfony2 framework. The first thing I have done is to include Doctrine.

I have installed Doctrine with the help of Composer and set up a bootstrap file for it. My entities, to avoid future complications, already follow the namespacing scheme `Company\BundleName\Entity\Object`. The following works:

```
$em->getRepository('Company\\BundleName\\Entity\\Object')
   ->find($id)
;
```

I was unable to find any reference of how to inform Doctrine of namespace aliases as Symfony2 does, so I can write

```
$em->getRepository('CompanyBundleName:Object')
   ->find($id)
;
```

instead. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Is your bundle set up correctly (with a CompanyBundle.php file, and registered in AppKernel.php)?

Comment: Did you read what I wrote? Nothing but Doctrine is set up yet - the plan is to migrate to Symfony2 in the future. There are no bundles yet - I just namespaced my entities like that to avoid problems in the future. I want to know how to *manually* setup namespace aliasing with Doctrine.

Comment: The functionality for this is set up in Symfony2 by the DoctrineBridge bundle, specifically the getMappingDriverBundleConfigDefaults function - https://github.com/symfony/DoctrineBridge/blob/master/DependencyInjection/AbstractDoctrineExtension.php#L166

If you want to reflect this functionality without Symfony2, you'll need to extend the Doctrine entity manager and generate the prefix yourself in the getRepository function. It is not part of the Doctrine system.

Comment: Thank you very much - this is exactly the information I was looking for.

Comment: No worries =) I'll put it in an actual answer instead of comments for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality for this is set up in Symfony2 by the DoctrineBridge bundle, specifically the [getMappingDriverBundleConfigDefaults function](https://github.com/symfony/DoctrineBridge/blob/master/DependencyInjection/AbstractDoctrineExtension.php#L166).

If you want to reflect this functionality without Symfony2, you'll need to extend the Doctrine entity manager and generate the prefix yourself in the getRepository function. It is not part of the Doctrine system.

Answer (score 5):

There is an easier way now:

```
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(...);
$config->addEntityNamespace('CompanyBundleName', 'Company\BundleName\Entity');
```

will do what you want. It took me several hours hunting to find this! Its not in the docs anywhere I could find.